# How to fix the memory leak while calling [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL] in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks

I Encountered a memory leak while checking with instruments at this specific line `NSURL *constantURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];` 
this line is used in validate the Appstore receipt

```
inline static NSData *GetConstantData(void)
{
    NSURL *constantURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *constantData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:constantURL];
    if (!constantData) {
       [NSException raise:@"MacAppStore Constant Validation Error" format:@"Failed to fetch the MacAppStore constant.", nil];

    }
    return constantData;
}
```

Here is the image from the instruments [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXErZ.png)

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

Try [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:] ,or Try to move constantData to outside.